# Prove that a $C^\infty$ vector field on $M$ can be extended to a $C^\infty$ vector field on $N$ .

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose a $C^\infty$ manifold $M$ is a closed regular submanifold of $N$. Prove that a $C^\infty$ vector field on $M$ can be extended to a $C^\infty$ vector field on $N$ .
I have no idea how to create vector field on $N$ with the condition"closed regular submanifold". Would you offer me some thoughts?

Comment: You have to create it locally first and then glue everything with a metric or partition of unity. Locally the regular condition just means that you have an inclusion of a euclidean space of inferior dimension. Can you solve this for an inclusion $\mathbb{R}^m \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: When you say you have a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$, are you assuming that for each $p\in M$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $N$ and a vector field $\tilde{X}$ on $V$ which agrees with $X$ on $V\cap M$?